# How to kill a tree of children of a parent process

Tags: c, process

I created a process that has 3 children. The problem is that I can't create any of these children without killing it at the end, when `fork()==0`.
My code is like:

```
for(i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
  if(fork()==0){
    //do child things
    exit(0);
  }
  else{
    //do parent things
  }
}
```

I'd like to create these 3 children without killing them, and, when they are created, kill them all.

PS: Sorry about my English :)

Comment: Hm. Who is forcing you to kill them?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. But talking abut killing children sounds like a bad idea (in whichever way).

Comment: @Olaf Making them zombies is not much better :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. In case you're a daemon yourself, it might be adequate ;)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The walking Forks?

Comment: @tofro: IIRC, daemon processes are owned by `init`, resp. process #1. Did that change with `upstart` etc.?

Comment: @Olaf no idea. But I guess they can still have zombie childs if done wrong the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of each child's pid.  Then at the end of the loop, you `kill` them.

```
pid_t child_pid[3];
for(i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
  child_pid[i] == fork();
  if (child_pid[i]==-1){
      perror("fork failed");
      exit(0);
  } else if (child_pid[i]==0){
    //do child things
    exit(0);
  }
  else{
    //do parent things
  }
}
for(i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    kill(child_pid[i], SIGKILL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't create any of these children without killing it at the end

The only thing I see in your example code that I can correlate with "killing" the children is their calls to `exit()`.  I wouldn't at all call that "killing" them, however; each child simply terminates normally when it executes the `exit()` at the end of its work.

Furthermore, nothing forces you to have the children `exit()` at that point.  If they do not exit, they simply continue out of the `if` block.  If you don't want them to fork their own children, then you could put in a `break` in place of the `exit()`, so that they break out of the surrounding loop.

That does beg the question of whether it makes sense to do that.  Unless there is in fact some work appropriate for the children to perform after leaving the loop, having them call `exit()`, as they now do, is the right thing to do.

Anyway, if you really do want to forcibly kill the child processes instead of letting them terminate normally, then @dbush demonstrates how you would do that.  Perhaps, however, you would prefer for the parent to *wait* after the loop until the children all terminate on their own.  In that case, instead of calling `kill()` as @dbush demonstrates, you can call `waitpid()`.  Note, too, that if you do manually kill the children then afterward you should *also* wait for them.  Only if you want the children to continue running independently should you fail to wait for them.